# Unexpected results from implementing an AAR library compared to source library in Android Projects

Tags: java, android, android-studio, aar

## Summary

### Current Behavior

Unexpected results from implementing an AAR library compared to source library in Android Projects.

- `super` keyword seems to be point to a grandparent class rather than the direct parent class.
- Somehow overridding a grandparent method even though same method is declared and overridden in parent.

Both issues only exist when using a compiled AAR of library, i.e. problem does not exist when implementing same project using library source code.

### Expected Behavior

- I would expect both calls to `super` to resolve to parent class.
- I would expect overriding `onCreate` to override the method in parent class not grandparent.

## Working App

I have an Android Application based in package `com.example.sourceapp`

This uses and manages the source code for a separate library located in `com.example.sourcelibrary`, in which is a class we'll call `ParentClass`.

In `ParentClass` I have two members of interest.

- A public boolean called `myBool` which originates in `ParentClass`
- An method overriding the `android.app.Activity.onCreate` method which is also overridden and inherited from some grandparent class `GrandparentClass` in some other library `com.example.someotherlibrary`.

In my `com.example.sourceapp.MainActivity` I do two things.

- I extend `com.example.sourcelibrary.ParentClass` and modify `myBool` contained within the `ParentClass` using `super.myBool = true;`.
- I call `onCreate` via `super.onCreate()` within the overridden method. 
  Both work as expected. When I hover over `super.onCreate` Android Studio indicates it to resolve properly to the parent class as expected.

## Not Working App

In a different Android Project `com.example.compiledapp.MainActivity` instead of depending on the source library `com.example.sourcelibrary`, I depend on a compiled (debug) AAR file made from the same library.

I import the needed class from the AAR package at the top of `com.example.compiledapp.MainActivity` with `import com.example.sourcelibrary.ParentClass` without any resolution issue.

Later in `com.example.compiledapp.MainActivity` I use the same code as before to

```
super.myBool = true;
super.onCreate()
```

but Android Studio indicates that it cannot resolve myBool in `super.myBool = true;`.

Furthermore, the 2nd line seems to resolve just fine, but upon closer inspection when I hover over it, Android Studio indicates that `onCreate` resolves to being a member of the grandparent class `com.example.someotherlibrary.GrandparentClass` instead of the parent class `com.example.sourcelibrary.ParentClass`.

Looking a few lines up, as I hover over the `onCreate` override, Android Studio indicates that I am overriding the `onCreate` from the grandparent class, not the parent class.

Why/How would `onCreate` skip the parent method and override the grandparent class?

Also it looks like the `super` keyword is resolving to the grandparent class rather than to the parent class. That is the only explanation I can think of that would result in `onCreate` resolving to the GrandparentClass and `myBool` not being resolvable. I didn't think this was how `super` worked.

Is this normal and I simply am misunderstanding something fundamental about inheritance? Maybe I am doing something wrong when compiling to AAR such that the parent variables/methods become inaccessible despite being declared public? Or maybe Android Studio gives preference to one package over another based on some rules I am unaware of?

## Working Code

```java
package com.example.sourceapp;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.sourcelibrary.ParentClass;

public class MainActivity extends ParentClass {

    // Shows to Override onCreate in ParentClass
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // super resolves to ParentClass
        super.myBool = true; // super resolves to ParentClass
    }

}
```

## Not Working Code

```java
package com.example.compiledapp;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.sourcelibrary.ParentClass;

public class MainActivity extends ParentClass {

    // Shows to Override onCreate in GrandparentClass
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // super resolves to Grandparent
        super.myBool = true; // does not resolve
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this something you just observe in the IDE (Android Studio) or do you see a problem at run-time as well?

Comment: Managed to figure it out. See my answer below. Will mark it as answer after the 2 day waiting period.

Comment: A thoroughly comprehensive question, great work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up tracking down the error. It turns out when building my `com.example.sourceapp`, which included the library module `com.example.sourcelibrary`, the build process was not updating the AAR file, and there was apparently something wrong/old in the outdated sourcelibrary code (maybe it was missing the onCreate method and myBool. Not sure really as I don't recall where in my git history it would have been since I only briefly noted the modified date was old, then rebuilt and the old timestamp is now gone.

Regardless, what helped was going to the gradle menu in Android Studio for the `com.example.sourceapp` and navigating to the sourcelibrary-->Tasks-->build-->build. Attempting to build the library directly threw an error related to SDK versions, so I fixed this and rebuilt, reimported to the compiledapp and it worked as expected.

The thing others may learn from this, is that if something strange is occurring with your AAR dependency, check that the source code you are building the AAR from is actually building and updating the AAR file, as Android Studio apparently doesn't throw an error when building the app that surrounds the library.

Maybe the SDK settings in the app level gradle overrode the library level gradle settings and allowed it to build the app without errors, and the updated library was actually built, but only within the APK? Not sure, exactly why, but at least an overall lesson was learned.